# how to write all list items from json one after another in react?

Tags: react-native, components, fetch

i want to show names on screen which i fetch from jsonplaceholder.com . all names are appearing at once but i want that names come one after another like 2sec.
i tried this ,but did not work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class UserList extends Component {
state={users:[],loading:true}
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
                .then(result => result.json())
                .then(jsonData =>this.setState({users:jsonData,loading:false}))
    }, 4000);
}

render() {
    
            <h1>USERS</h1>

            {this.state.loading && <h1>Loading..........</h1> }

            {this.state.users.length>0 && this.state.users.map(user=>
            setTimeout(() => {
                <div className="" key={user.id}>{user.name}</div>
            }, 3000)
                
             )}

        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, you componentDidUpdate to update the index

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class UserList extends Component {
  state = { users: [], loading: true, indexes: [] };
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((result) => result.json())
      .then((jsonData) => this.setState({ users: jsonData, loading: false }));
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { users, indexes } = this.state;

    if (indexes.length !== users.length) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          indexes: [...prevState.indexes, prevState.indexes.length]
        }));
      }, 2000);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { users, indexes, loading } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>USERS</h1>

        {loading && <h1>Loading..........</h1>}

        {users.length > 0 &&
          indexes.length > 0 &&
          indexes.map((index) => <div>{users[index].name}</div>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But i'll strongly recommend you use hooks for such updates.

Comment: thank you mate. names appears once and go .how all name can appear on the screen. i mean names will come one by one and will stay on screen.

Comment: @RidvanSaman i edited my answer. You can check